# Como seleccionar en Python en un TreeView una fila usando MVC (Modelo, Vista, Controlaor)

Tags: python, python-3.x, mvc, tkinter, grid

soy nuevo en Python pero me defiendo un poco.  He realizado un proyecto, pero quiero hacerlo con una estructura MVC (Modelo, Vista, Controlador). El tema es que quiero sacar un TreeView donde mostrar datos y cuando pulsen en una fila(row) realizar tareas, pero me casca el programa cuando hago click en una cualquier fila y da el siguiente error:

AttributeError: 'Controlador' object has no attribute 'master'

He quitado del proyecto todo y he dejado solo lo que nos interesa, los 3 archivos(clases) Modelo.py, Vista.py y Controlador.py y el TreeView en Vista.

También os dejo un archivo test con un TreeView donde sí que medio funciona.

El tema es recuperar la fila, o el indice de la fila. En cualquier caso un dato de la fila que permita saber cual ha sido seleccionada.

Saludos y Gracias de antemano.
Enrique

```
# MODELO (modelo.py)

class Modelo:

    datos = [1, 'ES', 'España', 34,
            2, 'FR', 'Francia', 33,
            3, 'GR', 'Alemania', 49,
            4, 'IT', 'Italia', 39,
            5, 'GB', 'Reino Unido', 44]

    def __init__(self):
        self.datos.append(5)
        self.datos.append('PT')
        self.datos.append('Portugal')
        self.datos.append(351)

    def set_datos(self, dato, i):
        self.datos[i] = dato[i]

    def get_datos(self, i):
        return self.datos[i]

# CONTROLADOR (controlador.py)

##############################################################
# APLICACION PYTHON 3                                        #
# Pograma principal                                          #
##############################################################
import sys

from modelo import Modelo
from vista import Vista


class Controlador:

    def __init__(self):
        self.modelo = Modelo()
        self.vista = Vista(self)

    def update_treeview_paises(self):
        for i in range(6):
            print(i)
            self.vista.treeview_paises.insert('', 'end', text=str(self.modelo.get_datos((i*4)+0)),
                                                  values=(self.modelo.get_datos((i*4)+1),
                                                          self.modelo.get_datos((i*4)+2),
                                                          self.modelo.get_datos((i*4)+3)),
                                                          tags=("item",))

    def main(self):
        self.update_treeview_paises()
        self.vista.main()

    def salir(self):
        sys.exit(0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    controlador = Controlador()
    controlador.main()


# VISTA (vista.py)

import os
import sys
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

from tkinter import scrolledtext, NSEW, W
from typing import re


class Vista(tk.Tk):
    PAD = 5

    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__()
        self.master = master
        self.title("Menú Principal")
        self.config(bg='lightgrey', borderwidth=1)


        # Frame Principal
        self.frm_main = ttk.Frame(self, relief='ridge')
        self.frm_main.pack(padx=self.PAD, pady=self.PAD, fill="both", expand='yes')

        sw = self.winfo_screenwidth()
        sh = self.winfo_screenheight()
        w = sw * 0.7
        h = sh * 0.7
        x = (sw - w) / 2
        y = (sh - h) / 2
        self.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (w, h, x, y))
        self.state('zoomed')  # Maximizada

        # Dibujamos la Barra de Menú
        self.menubar = tk.Menu(self)
        self.config(menu=self.menubar, bg="lightgrey", highlightcolor="white", highlightthickness="1")

        self.filemenu = tk.Menu(self.menubar, tearoff=0)
        self.filemenu.add_command(label="Nuevo")
        self.filemenu.add_command(label="Abrir")
        self.filemenu.add_command(label="Bandeja")
        self.filemenu.add_separator()
        self.filemenu.add_command(label="Salir", command=self.salir)

        self.editmenu = tk.Menu(self.menubar, tearoff=0)
        self.editmenu.add_command(label="Cortar")
        self.editmenu.add_command(label="Copiar")
        self.editmenu.add_command(label="Pegar")

        self.datosmenu = tk.Menu(self.menubar, tearoff=0)

        self.subdatos = tk.Menu(self.datosmenu, tearoff=0)
        self.subdatos.add_command(label="Datos")
        self.datosmenu.add_cascade(label='Recoger Datos',underline=0)

        self.helpmenu = tk.Menu(self.menubar, tearoff=0)
        self.helpmenu.add_command(label="Ayuda")
        self.helpmenu.add_separator()
        self.helpmenu.add_command(label="Acerca de...")

        self.menubar.add_cascade(label="Archivo", menu=self.filemenu)
        self.menubar.add_cascade(label="Editar", menu=self.editmenu)
        self.menubar.add_cascade(label="Datos", menu=self.datosmenu)
        self.menubar.add_cascade(label="Ayuda", menu=self.helpmenu)

        # Titulo
        self.lbl_tit = tk.Label(self.frm_main, fg='black', bg='lightgrey', text="Main Menu")
        self.lbl_tit.pack()

        # Frame de arriba
        self.frm_up = ttk.Frame(self.frm_main)
        self.frm_up.pack(fill='x', padx=self.PAD, pady=self.PAD)

        # Database
        self.frm_dat = tk.LabelFrame(self.frm_up, text="Database")
        self.frm_dat.pack(side='right')
        self.lbl_dat = tk.Label(self.frm_dat, text='')

        self.lbl_dat.pack()

        # Frame de arriba y central
        self.frm_upc = ttk.Frame(self.frm_up)
        self.frm_upc.pack(anchor='center', padx=self.PAD, pady=self.PAD)

        # IA
        self.frm_ia = tk.LabelFrame(self.frm_upc, text="Inteligencia \n Artificial")
        self.frm_ia.pack(side='left')
        self.lbl_ia = tk.Label(self.frm_ia, fg='red', text="OFF")
        self.lbl_ia.pack()

        # Frame Cuadro Datos
        self.frm_cpa = ttk.Frame(self.frm_main)
        self.frm_cpa.pack(fill='x', padx=self.PAD, pady=self.PAD)

        # TREEVIEW PAISES
        self.frm_cpf = tk.LabelFrame(self.frm_cpa, text="Paises")
        self.frm_cpf.pack(fill='x', expand='yes', side='left')

        estilo = ttk.Style()
        estilo.configure("Treeview", highlightthickness=0, bd=0, font=('Calibri', 10))
        estilo.configure("Treeview.Heading", font=('Calibri', 10, 'bold'), foreground='#3790D5')

        self.treeview_paises = ttk.Treeview(self.frm_cpf, style="Treeview", columns=('Nº', 'ISO', 'País', 'Codigo'))
        self.treeview_paises.heading('#0', text='Nº')
        self.treeview_paises.heading('#1', text='ISO')
        self.treeview_paises.heading('#2', text='País')
        self.treeview_paises.heading('#3', text='Código')
        self.treeview_paises.column('#0', minwidth=80, width=80, stretch=True, anchor="c")
        self.treeview_paises.column('#1', minwidth=80, width=80, stretch=True, anchor="c")
        self.treeview_paises.column('#2', minwidth=80, width=80, stretch=True, anchor="c")
        self.treeview_paises.column('#3', minwidth=100, width=100, stretch=True, anchor="c")

        self.treeview_paises.tag_bind("item", '<<TreeviewSelect>>', self.selecciono_pais)
        self.treeview_paises.tag_bind('item', "<Double-Button-1>", self.selecciono_pais)

        self.treeview_paises.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=NSEW)

        vsb_a = ttk.Scrollbar(self.frm_cpf, orient="vertical", command=self.treeview_paises.yview)
        vsb_a.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=NSEW)
        hsb_a = ttk.Scrollbar(self.frm_cpf, orient="horizontal", command=self.treeview_paises.xview)
        hsb_a.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=NSEW)
        self.treeview_paises.configure(xscrollcommand=hsb_a.set, yscrollcommand=vsb_a.set)

        # Boton x de cerrar ventana la oculta
        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.on_closing)

    def main(self):
        self.mainloop()

    def salir(self):
        self.master.salir()
        self.destroy()
        os._exit(0)
        sys.exit(0)

    def on_closing(self):
        self.withdraw()

    def selecciono_pais(self, event):
        print('Seleccionado pais')
        #item = self.treeview_paises.identify('item', event.x, event.y)
        #print("you clicked on", self.treeview_paises.item(item, "text"))

    def filter(self, tree, col, descending):
        print ('Row: {} & Column: {} '.format(
            re.sub('I00', '', str(tree.identify_row(tree.winfo_pointerxy()[1] - tree.winfo_rooty()))),
            re.sub(r'#', '', str(tree.identify_column(tree.winfo_pointerxy()[0] - tree.winfo_rootx())))))

# TEST (test.py)

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class Application(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, main_window):
        super().__init__(main_window)
        main_window.title("Vista de árbol en Tkinter")

        self.treeview = ttk.Treeview(self)
        # Crear una nueva etiqueta.
        self.treeview.tag_bind("mytag", "<<TreeviewSelect>>", self.item_selected)
        self.treeview.tag_bind("mytag", "<<TreeviewOpen>>",
                              self.item_opened)
        self.treeview.tag_bind("mytag", "<<TreeviewClose>>",
                              self.item_closed)

        # Añadir dos elementos indicando la etiqueta anterior para
        # que respondan a los eventos.
        item = self.treeview.insert("", tk.END, text="Elemento 1", tags=("mytag",))
        item = self.treeview.insert("", tk.END, text="Elemento 2", tags=("mytag",))
        self.treeview.insert(item, tk.END, text="Subelemento 1", tags=("mytag",))

        self.treeview.pack()

        self.pack()

    def item_selected(self, event):
        """Item seleccionado."""
        print("Seleccionado.")
        #item = self.treeview.identify('mytag', event.x, event.y)
        #print("you clicked on", self.treeview.item(item, "mytag"))

    def item_opened(self, event):
        """Item abierto."""
        print("Abierto.")

    def item_closed(self, event):
        """Item cerrado."""
        print("Cerrado.")

main_window = tk.Tk()
app = Application(main_window)
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

La clase que hereda de `tk.Tk`, que en tu caso es la clase `Vista`, ha de contener un atributo llamado `master` que sea una referencia a la "ventana" que contiene esa vista.

Tal como lo tienes programado, le pasas el valor de ese `master` como parámetro al constructor, y lo guardas en un atributo de la vista, aquí:

```
# En el fichero vista.py

class Vista(tk.Tk):
    PAD = 5

    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__()
        self.master = master
        ...
```

Sin embargo, cuando instancias la clase `Vista` (cosa que haces desde la clase controlador), lo que le pasas como parámetro no es una ventana Tk. Lo haces así:

```
# En el fichero controlador.py

class Controlador:

    def __init__(self):
        self.modelo = Modelo()
        self.vista = Vista(self)
```

Como ves, le estás pasando `self` a la `Vista`, y en este caso `self` es el propio objeto controlador, el cual no es una ventana Tk válida porque no hereda de ninguna clase de la biblioteca tkinter.

En realidad, en este caso en que la vista directamente es la "ventana principal", y no un sub-frame, no necesitas inicializar el atributo `self.master`, ni pasárselo al constructor, ya que esto lo hace por defecto `super()`.

Así pues la solución consiste en, por un lado, quitar ese parámetro del constructor de la `Vista`, así como su asignación, y dejarlo así:

```
# En el fichero vista.py

class Vista(tk.Tk):
    PAD = 5

    def __init__(self):             # Constructor ahora sin parámetros
        super().__init__()
        #  self.master = master     # <-- Esta línea eliminada
```

y por otro lado no pasarle ningún parámetro a este constructor cuando lo llamas desde el controlador:

```
# En el fichero controlador.py

class Controlador:

    def __init__(self):
        self.modelo = Modelo()
        self.vista = Vista()      # Sin parámetros
```

He verificado que con estos cambios ya no se produce el error mencionado.

Comment: Jo, qué maravilla muchísimas gracias. Llevo varios días con esto y como llevo poco con python ya no sabía qué manual leerme más, jajaja. Tienes unas cervezas pagadas.

Comment: Jaja. Gracias por la cerveza. También puedes marcar como aceptada la respuesta ;-)

Comment: Bien, en cuanto pueda te votaré, que aún ni me deja .. me dice algo así... ¡Gracias por tu comentario! Los votos emitidos por quienes tienen menos de 15 de reputación se registran, pero no cambian la puntuación que se muestra públicamente. Saludos ¡